# How to test whether all values of a hash equal a given value

Tags: perl

I'm dealing with hashes like:

```
my %hash1 = (
  key1 => 0,
  key2 => 1,
  key3 => 0,
);
```

I want to do something if the value of *all* values (not just one value) of `%hash1` is 1.

How to write that?

For reference, I can write:

```
for $key ( keys %hash1 ) {
   if ( $hash1{$key} == 1 ){
    #do something
   }
}
```

which is wrong because even if one key has a value equal to 1, the `#do something` part of the code will run. The code I wrote apparently does something if at least one key equals 1. It would be nice to have something like:

```
for $key ( keys %hash1 ) {
   if ( exists( $hash1{$key} == 1 ) ){
    #do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do:

```
my $not_all_ones = grep { $_ != 1 } values %hash1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `List::MoreUtils`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/all/;

if (all { $_ == 1 } values %hash) {
  # iterate the hash
  while (my ($k, $v) = each %hash) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The `all { something($_) } @list` is a fancy way of writing

```
!grep { !something($_) } @list
```

which uses [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Note that `my %hash = { key => 1 }` does not create the data structure you wanted. Rather, this maps a key `"HASH(0x1234567)"` to `undef`. If you `use warnings`, you'll get a message telling you that you are using a (hash) reference where a list was expected. Initialize hashes with a key-value list: `my %hash = ( key => 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Set a flag within the `if` and check its value after the loop.

```
$all_are_one = $all_are_one && $hash1{$key} == 1
```

You would need to set it to true before the loop